# Passing python array to bash script (and passing bash variable to python function)

Tags: python, bash

I have written a Python module which contains functions that return arrays. I want to be able to access the string arrays returned from the python module, and iterate over in a bash script, so I may iterate over the array elements.

For example:

## Python module (mymod)

```
def foo():
    return ('String', 'Tuple', 'From', 'Python' )

def foo1(numargs):
    return [x for x in range(numargs)]
```

## Bash script

```
foo_array  = .... # obtain array from mymod.foo()
for i in "${foo_array[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done


foo1_array = .... # obtain array from mymod.foo1(pass arg count from bash)
for j in "${foo1_array[@]}"
do
    echo $j
done
```

How can I implement this in bash?.

**version Info:**

Python 2.6.5
bash: 4.1.5

Comment: The easiest way to get things in and out of a script is probably through stdin/stdout.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Second try - this time shell takes the integration brunt.

Given *foo.py* containing this:

```
def foo():
        foo = ('String', 'Tuple', 'From', 'Python' )
        return foo
```

Then write your bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=`python -c 'from foo import *; print " ".join(foo())'`
for x in $FOO:
do
        echo "This is foo.sh: $x"
done
```

The remainder is first answer that drives integration from the Python end.

*Python*

```
import os
import subprocess

foo = ('String', 'Tuple', 'From', 'Python' )

os.putenv('FOO', ' '.join(foo))

subprocess.call('./foo.sh')
```

*bash*

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in $FOO
do
        echo "This is foo.sh: $x"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I want my Python module to be agnostic of who/what is calling it (separation of concerns) - the code you suggested requires modifying the python code - which is not ideal.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli OK - hope I understood it right now - the new code uses shell to drive the integration.

Comment: YES! - that intuitively makes sense!. Thanks very much!. Just tried it and it works :)

Comment: BTW, I am guessing that to pass a value from bash to Python, I generate the string in bash and use the -c option to pass from bash->python?. To pass compound data types (e.g. array), I probably need to write a wrapper function at the python end to parse in the passed value(s) - is my assumption correct, or is there a better way to pass data from bash -> python function?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Your suggestion will work - you can also pass it via environment variable like this `python -c "import os; print os.getenv('HOME')"`

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can tell python process to read STDIN with "-" as in

```
echo "print 'test'" | python -
```

Now you can define [multiline snippets](https://serverfault.com/questions/72476/clean-way-to-write-complex-multi-line-string-to-a-variable) of python code and pass them into subshell

```
FOO=$( python - <<PYTHON

def foo():
    return ('String', 'Tuple', 'From', 'Python')

print ' '.join(foo())

PYTHON
)

for x in $FOO
do
    echo "$x"
done
```

You can also use **env** and **set** to list/pass environment and local variables from bash to python (into ".." strings).

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of something like object serialization, perhaps one way is to print a list of comma separated values and pipe them from the command line.

Then you can  do something like:

```
> python script.py | sh shellscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps too. script.py:

```
 a = ['String','Tuple','From','Python']

    for i in range(len(a)):

            print(a[i])
```

and then we make the following bash script pyth.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

python script.py > tempfile.txt
readarray a < tempfile.txt
rm tempfile.txt

for j in "${a[@]}"
do 
      echo $j
done
```

sh pyth.sh

Answer (score 0):

As well as Maria's method to obtain output from python, you can use the `argparse` library to input variables to python scripts from bash; there are tutorials and further docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for python 3 and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) for python 2.

An example python script `command_line.py`:

```py
import argparse
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('x', type=int)

    parser.add_argument('array')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(type(args.x))
    print(type(args.array))
    print(2 * args.x)

    str_array = args.array.split(',')
    print(args.x * np.array(str_array, dtype=int))
```

Then, from a terminal:

```sh
$ python3 command_line.py 2 0,1,2,3,4
```

```sh
# Output
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
4
[0 2 4 6 8]
```