# How do I pass Python arrays to shell script as an Array?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script (test.sh) in which I am using bash arrays like this -

```
#!/bin/bash

...

echo $1
echo $2

PARTITION=(0 3 5 7 9)

for el in "${PARTITION[@]}"
do
    echo "$el"
done

...
```

As of now, I have hardcoded the values of PARTITION array in my shell script as you can see above..

Now I have a Python script as mentioned below from which I am calling test.sh shell script by passing certain parameters such as `hello1` and `hello2` which I am able to receive as `$1` and `$2`. Now how do I pass `jj['pp']` and `jj['sp']` from my Python script to Shell script and then iterate over that array as I am doing currently in my bash script?

Below script doesn't work if I am passing `jj['pp']`

```
import subprocess
import json
import os

hello1 = "Hello World 1"
hello2 = "Hello World 2"

jsonData = '{"pp": [0,3,5,7,9], "sp": [1,2,4,6,8]}'
jj = json.loads(jsonData)

print jj['pp']
print jj['sp']

# foo = (0, 3, 5, 7, 9)

# os.putenv('FOO', ' '.join(foo))

print "start"
subprocess.call(['./test.sh', hello1, hello2, jj['pp']])
print "end"
```

**UPDATE:-**

Below JSON document is going to be in this format only -

```
jsonData = '{"pp": [0,3,5,7,9], "sp": [1,2,4,6,8]}'
```

so somehow I need to convert this to bash arrays while passing to shell script..

Comment: Encoding it probably the best way. Find a encoding that works equal between Python and Bash :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Python*

```
import os
import json
import subprocess

hello1 = "Hello World 1"
hello2 = "Hello World 2"

jsonData = '{"pp": [0,3,5,7,9], "sp": [1,2,4,6,8]}'
jj = json.loads(jsonData)

print jj['pp']
print jj['sp']

os.putenv( 'jj', ' '.join( str(v) for v in jj['pp']  ) )

print "start"
subprocess.call(['./test.sh', hello1, hello2 ])
print "end"
```

*bash*

```
echo $1
echo $2

for el in $jj
do
    echo "$el"
done
```

Taken from here: [Passing python array to bash script (and passing bash variable to python function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392033/passing-python-array-to-bash-script-and-passing-bash-variable-to-python-functio)

Comment: Can you please provide an example basis on my scenario? I tried doing this in the way but it doesn't work for me.. Take a look in jsonStr document it is not in the format in which you have declared foo variable..

Comment: Thanks.. Yeah there is an error..     `os.putenv('jj', ' '.join(jj['pp']))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found` Not sure how to fix it.. I know its a pretty simple problem I guess but this is my third day with Python so lot of things are little bit rusty to me.. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: ok updated with input from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880813/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-int-found, join needs the elements to be strings ;-)