# What is best way to return an array value form a Python in a bash script?

Tags: python, shell

I wanted to use python return  /sys.exit value as variable for further processing.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat myjson.json | \
output=($(python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);
                     result =[];
                         for y in [x["_source"]["memberId"] for x in obj["hits"]["hits"]]:
                             result+=[y];
                      sys.exit(result)'))
echo 'output'$output
```

what is the best approach to read JSON data in the shell script using Python and store the Python output in an array variable of shell script

Comment: `sys.exit()` can only return integer values.  If you want json, that will have to be printed as regular output.  Or written to a file, saved to a database, etc.

Comment: On a side note, depending on your requirement, you may consider using powerful Linux tools such as grep, awk, sed. Believe it or not, these tools are way faster and works flawlessly on a shell.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392033/passing-python-array-to-bash-script-and-passing-bash-variable-to-python-functio

Comment: @RaviJoshi, structure-unaware tools should absolutely not be used to parse structured languages like JSON or XML; those are why we have specialty tools like `jq` or `xmlstarlet` specializing in their handling while being intentionally easy to use from scripts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: right said. it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text captured in `output` is the stuff *printed* by the Python command to standard output. `sys.exit` only sets the *exit code* of the command, which can be captured as `$?` before running another command.